# Configuring TexMaker and BibTex

Tags: bibtex, texmaker

I'm using Windows 7 and just installed Texmaker.
Is it possible to configure it in such a way that I can run Latex -> BibTex -> Latex -> Latex?

I looked at the configuration options here:

[image]

I tried replacing the `bibtex %` line with
`pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex bibtex % pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` but that did not work.

What should I change to be able to run this command?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, go to `Options`->`Configure TeXmaker`->`Quickbuild`->`User`->`Wizard`, and then add the commands in succession. You can also do this manually by separating adjacent commands with a vertical bar.

Comment: Can you share an commands for Latex -> BibTex -> Latex -> Latex?

Comment: @Jacek: Maybe you are interested in the following question/answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/integration-of-arara-in-texmaker

Answer (score 1):

Under "Quick Build", click User and type this:

```
pdflatex %.tex|bibtex %.aux|makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls|pdflatex %.tex|pdflatex %.tex|"C:/Program Files/Adobe/Reader 11.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe" %.pdf
```